# TypeError: chatManager.connect(...) is undefined

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am trying to use chatkit api in my react js project but I am getting the following error:

TypeError: chatManager.connect(...) is undefined
componentDidMount
C:/Users/admin/chat-app/src/App.js:33
  30 | 
  31 |
  32 |

> 33 | chatManager.connect().then(currentUser=> {
>        | ^  34 |    currentUser.subscribeToRoom({
>     35 |       roomId:19436903,
>     36 |       hooks:{

```
import React from 'react';
import Chatkit from 'pusher-chatkit-client';
import connect from 'pusher-chatkit-server';

//import Chatkit from 'pusher/chatkit';

import './App.css';
import RoomList from './RoomList';
import MessageList from './MessageList';
import SendMessageForm from './SendMessageForm';
import NewRoomForm from './CreateRoomForm';
//import {tokenUrl , instanceLocator} from './config.js';



class App extends React.Component
{

  componentDidMount()
  {
    const chatManager=new Chatkit.ChatManager
    ({
      instanceLocator:'v1:us1:a34c45b2-2af9-4f63-a532-fe189495f655',
      userId:'manju',
      tokenProvider:new Chatkit.TokenProvider
      ({
        url:'https://us1.pusherplatform.io/services/chatkit_token_provider/v1/a34c45b2-2af9-4f63-a532-fe189495f655/token'
      })
    });



  chatManager.connect().then(currentUser=> {
     currentUser.subscribeToRoom({
        roomId:19436903,
        hooks:{
          onNewMessage:message=>{
            console.log('message.text :',message.text);
          }
        }
      })
      })

  }
```

TypeError: chatManager.connect(...) is undefined
componentDidMount
C:/Users/admin/chat-app/src/App.js:33
  30 | 
  31 |
  32 |

> 33 | chatManager.connect().then(currentUser=> {
>        | ^  34 |    currentUser.subscribeToRoom({
>     35 |       roomId:19436903,
>     36 |       hooks:{